# Access Telephone Number suggestion on EditText Field on android

Tags: android, phone-number

I wrote an sms sending application using the instructions [Here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android). Now I want to add a suggestion for the phone number when the number or name is typed according to the number saved in the phone book i.e like when we enter number to call it suggests a number(dynamically on typing).

Is it possible to do or not? If possible then How Can I do this?I have used API level 2.2.

**Edit**:
I have do this with the help of Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758107/android-autocomplete-textview-and-cursoradapter) But When I click on the name from phone-book,it place name on text-box but I have need the number to send sms.

**Question**: How could I get number so that I can sent message to the selected name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can change fetch the existing numbers in your phone with [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html), change your phone number EditText to an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete), and use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) to bind the numbers from your contacts to the AutoCompleteTextView.

---

**Addition**
If you want to convert a contact name into a phone number you can try this in your "Submit" Button's `onClick()` method:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " = '" + autoComplete.getText() + "'", 
        null, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    phoneNo = cursor.getString(0);
```

Understand that this only gets the first number from the first contact that matches the name from your AutoCompleteTextView. You'll have to discern a way to distinguish between contacts with the same name and contact with multiple numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your response... later I had solve this with help of  [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938724/how-to-get-phone-number-from-person-name-which-are-in-my-contact-list-in-android) ... at last but not least thanks for guiding me toward the right direction...